# Stop IntelliJ from wrapping lines

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, code-formatting

In the JIndent formatter you can add "special" comments that prevent the formatter from processing a group of lines (//J-, //J+, if I remember correctly).

Is there an equivalent for the built-in formatter in IntelliJ IDEA (9.0.3 CE)? I'm normally very anal about my code style :-), but one of my colleagues is writing a chunk of SQL (in Strings) that should not be wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see a reply to [How to selectively disable IntelliJ IDEA code formatter with comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-selectively-disable-intellij-idea-code-formatter-with-comments/)

I believe that it covers this case too. Using external formatter plug-in which supports such feature would be a solution.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but, oh well.