# How to disable code formatting for some part of the code using comments?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'd like to selectively disable [the IntelliJ IDEA code formatter](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/code_formatting.html) for a portion of code [just like I can in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908). Does IntelliJ support this feature, and if so, how do I use it?

Comment: Official Documentation for skipping some part of the code using comments: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformatting-source-code.html#d859106e110

Comment: This feature should be definitively enabled by default! It would be nice

Answer (score 773, accepted):

Since version 13 it's possible to wrap the code with

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

**IntelliJ IDEA v.2018+:**

> File > Settings > Editor > Code Style

**IntelliJ IDEA v.2016+:**

> Preferences > Editor > Code Style

**IntelliJ IDEA v.14+:**

> Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Formatter Control

You can change the formatter control markers, as long as they're in comments.

---

Ensure formatter markers in comments are enabled, as shown in the following figure:

[image: Formatter Control Preference]

Comment: Currently, `@formatter:on` (or whatever you define) does nothing unless `@formatter:off` was already present. There are likely other ways of turning off reformatting -- or getting the editor to not reformat your code automatically. Search your preferences. This setting is to control sections that shouldn't be reformatted when manually performing a "Reformat", for instance.

Comment: You must go to `Preferences`->`Code Style`->`General`->`Formatter Control` and check `Enable formatter markers in comments` for this to work.

Comment: In 14, this is in Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Formatter Control

Comment: In the 2016.x version it's found in Settings > Editor > Code Style.

Comment: Another thing is that you actually can amend the markers. Then if you want to use above example your markers must match.

Comment: Why does this option disabled by default? It seems very useful to put markers in the code and restrict formatting for the whole team.

Comment: one thing to note here: for html, I've seen the @formatter notation seem to have no effect when deep inside tags or template blocks

Comment: Note that `// @formatter: off` will not work (only without white-space)

Comment: @TimurYarosh there is a ticket for it in the Intellij IDEA youtrack, feel free to upvote it, maybe Jetbrains will finally implement it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118043

Comment: is possible only for java format? for XML files? tnx

Answer (score 190):

Note for Carlos' answer of `@formatter:off` and `@formatter:on` to work, you may need to enable the preference first:

[image: In IntelliJ Preferences, under Code Style, General, Formatter Control there is a checkbox "Enable formatter markers in comments"]

Discovered via [How to config intellij-idea not format some part of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020200/how-to-config-intellij-idea-not-format-some-part-of-the-code)

[IDEA-56995](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56995) Disabled code formatting per region using comments

Comment: I want to disable this on entire project

Comment: Search preferences for "Reformat" to see checkboxes for quite a few of the ways IntelliJ reformats code automatically: on paste, on typing a closing brace, from templates... You can really dig in if you want to change the functionality. Not that it always makes sense. Use IntelliJ's support if asking a question, or their bug tracker if making a suggestion.

Comment: It's equally possible that enabling regular expressions, then using `.` as your formatter off instruction might work. So long as the first line in your file can be reformatted. No guarantees though. :)

Answer (score 35):

In xml files, use:

```xml
<!-- @formatter:off -->
<!-- @formatter:on -->
```

Comment: Doesn't work in xml files. Android Studio 3.4.1 based on Intelli-J.

Comment: It doesn't work in IntelliJ IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 unless you enable then, in “File/Settings/Editor/Code Style“, in “Formatter Control” section.

Comment: Works in Rider.

Answer (score 9):

Obsolete answer from 2010:

No, it's not possible right now, I've [submitted a new issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-56995) which you can track.

As a temporary solution you can use [external formatter plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=1605) for IDEA which can utilize Eclipse code formatter (I didn't check whether this particular option is supported).

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to exclude entire files (like regression test data xmls) from formatting. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167112

Answer (score -1):

A related question is how to stop IntelliJ formatting all files of a certain extension. I recently started using ktlint for my codebase and wanted IntelliJ to not interfere.

Using the ktlint IntelliJ plugin, I setup ktlint to run on any save in distract-free mode.

Under Tools -> Action on Save I modified the reformat code action to exclude Kotlin files.

Under Keymap, I modified the Reformat Code command to not use the hot key I normally use for saving (CMD-s).

Under Keymap, I modified the Save All command to have the hotkey CMD-s.

Current for IntelliJ 2023.3.3, Ktlint IntelliJ plugin 0.21.0