# How to config intellij-idea not format some part of the code?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

In a html file, there is some code used custom template-language:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ($scope, JsRoutes) {
        $scope.rows = [
            ${"#{list rows, as: 'row', separator: ','}"}
            {
            #{list fieldConfigs, as: 'f', separator: ','}
            ${f.name} : ${'$'}{row.${f.name}.toJson()}#{/list}
            }
            ${'#{/list}'}
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Is it possible to configure intellij-idea not to format it(but format the other part of the document)? Since idea will make it hard to read after formatting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ($scope, JsRoutes) {
        $scope.rows = [
            ${"#{list rows, as: 'row', separator: ','}"}
            {
    #{list fieldConfigs, as: 'f', separator: ','}
    ${f.name} :
        ${'$'}{
            row.${f.name}.toJson()
        }#{/list}
    }
    ${'#{/list}'}
    ]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable code formatter for some part of the code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatter-for-some-part-of-the-code)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This feature has been implemented and you can now disable formatting for the regions of code using the special comments.

[image: markers]

After enabling this feature in the settings, add `//@formatter:off` at the start of your region, and `//@formatter:on` at the end of it.

These are the default markers, and they are configurable.

You can find [more details and examples in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformatting-source-code.html):

- [Skipping a region when reformatting source code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/reformatting-source-code.html#d1971795e110)
- [Example of using formatting markers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/reformatting-source-code.html#d1971795e166)

---

Original answer from 2012:

<s>It's not possible yet, please vote for this feature request:</s>

- [IDEA-56995](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56995) Disable code formatting per region using comments

Comment: I don't want to use comments on my code just for intellij not to destroy my indentation I have worked so hard to get aligned, for instance defining properties. 

This setting should be available on full project, without a comment. 

But I want to be able to reformat when I say format, or indent.

Now I am left with possibly turning off the functionality completely by walking through the Java code style and checking boxes.

Comment: This has been fixed - see below for how to enable it.

Answer (score 51):

In my version EAP 13.1, you must enable the following option in settings,

`Preferences` -> `Code Style` -> `General` -> `Formatter Control` -> `Enable formatter markers in comments`

before you can use these comments,

```
// @formatter:off

// @formatter:on
```

or these (depending on language):

```
<!--@formatter:off-->

<!--@formatter:on-->
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot highlighting the checkbox for Enable formatter markers in comments under Preferences]

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you!
I think this should be the accepted answer as it was meanwhile added as a feature to IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 9):

Since [EAP 13](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/9b42e988a9a0ab56159173aaafd2852ea7dc2cdd) you can trigger the formatter with the following comments:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

To enable it in  "surround with", you can define a Live Template in the section "surround" with:

```
// @formatter:off
$SELECTION$
// @formatter:off
```

You can find these settings in `Settings` -> `Code Style` -> `General` and set your own trigger words.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that the formatter control does not appear to work in javadoc comments. It needs to be either in a regular C or C++-style comment. So `// @formatter:off` works `/* @formatter:off */` also works, but `/** @formatter:off */` does not.