# How to stop IntelliJ IDEA from removing empty lines from .properties files?

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

How to stop IntelliJ IDEA from removing empty lines from .properties files?
I want to use empty lines to separate sections of files (database properties, RabbitMQ properties, business properties, etc).

When file is saved, empty lines are removed.
I have IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2, with 'Save actions' and 'Properties' plugins.
I see no option to controll empty lines in .properties files anywhere.

Comment: wrap file with #@formatter:off #@formatter:on (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IntelliJ does that when you run Reformat Code action.

It can be disabled by disabling "Formatting actions -> Reformat file" in the Save Actions plugin settings. However, by doing this all your files are of course not being reformatted upon save.

There is blank lines settings for java code in Settings -> Editor -> Java -> Blank lines, but unfortunately not for property files as far as I know.

Better way to prevent reformatting would be just to add property file exclusion using the following regex

`.*/.*\.properties`

However, there seems to be issue currently which ignores this settings in some cases

> https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions/issues/29

Edit: issue is resolved in 0.11 version of the plugin. Exclusion regex works properly.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed work of Save Actions plugin. Disabling 'Activate save actions', or disabling 'reformat file' in save actions settings leaves blank lines in properties files.

I tried to exclude properties file from save actions, providing .*/.*\.properties as 'file path exclusions' in save action settings, but this does not work ..

Comment: Tried the exclusion suggested by their hint and does not work for me either.

Comment: It seems to be bug in plugin indeed (file exclusions are ignored). I have project files in same directory as source code (linked bug is for case when project files are in different directory as source files) but bug still occurs for me and file exclusions are ignored.

Comment: Update your plugin to version 11 it should work now with multiple modules and the exclusion regex `.*\.properties`, see https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions/issues/29 @BartoszBilicki

Comment: @Alexandre DuBreuil I confirm that exclusion works in 0.11 version. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

This is a bug in 2016.1 and 2016.2:
[IntelliJ Bug IDEA-157903](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157903)

This will be fixed in 2016.3, you can try the [IntelliJ EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.3+EAP)

As a **workaround**, I defined `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `s` to be the *Save All*, so when I notice that IntelliJ delets my blank lines, I issue an undo and use the shortcut with `Shift` to save the file without reformating.

**Update November 2016:** I can confirm that a option to keep blank lines in property files was added in version 2016.3

[image]

Comment: I am using below Intellij stable release, but still see the issue.`IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3
Build #IC-163.7743.44, built on November 17, 2016`

Comment: They fixed it by adding an option in the settings dialog.