# Android studio is reformatting my comments when I use CTRL ALT + L

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, format, comments

How do I prevent Android Studio from formatting my comments and only my code? I've been trying to search a solution for this on Google and using the Find Action key, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the preference first:
In IntelliJ Preferences, under Code Style, General, Formatter Control there is a checkbox "Enable formatter markers in comments"[image: These option you will see on android stdio]

Now for more description you can see :- [How to disable code formatting for some part of the code using comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments)