# Android Studio:Reformatting code leads blank before comment

Tags: android-studio

When using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Windows, Android Studio will reformat the code. But when there are some comments inside, things go wrong:

[image]

Once I reformat code, there will be more blank space before the contents in `blockquote`:

[image]

How to reformat the code like I expect?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link, which could be a workaround for you. 
[How to disable code formatting for some part of the code using comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments)

First, enable this option. 
Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Formatter Control 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5MHL.png

Then, write comments like this.

```
// @formatter:off
/*
YOUR COMMENTS
/*
// @formatter:on
```