# IntelliJ formatting license header

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2016.2.4 Community Edition and I have configured it so it autoformats my code (mostly Java or XML) when saving the file. This unfortunately includes that IntelliJ formats my license header (e.g. Apache license), which I create and validate via a Maven plugin com.mycila:license-maven-plugin.

How can I configure IntelliJ so that it does not reformat the license header?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments ?

Comment: I haven't, but this is not an option for me, since the license header check does not accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure formatters but i'm not sure this is what you're looking for.[image: Enable EditorConfig support] Editor > Code Style. You need to add 
`// @formatter:off` at the beginning and  `// @formatter:on` at the end of the ignored area.

*Update:*
I've tested Apache License block at the very beginning of the Java source. And used single asterisks comment block instead of double asterisks(`/**`)
`/*
*
* ...
*/`

And Intellij is ignoring them and not touching to formatting at all.

Comment: Yeah, that does not format the header, but the Maven plugin to check for the license header does not accept this. I need the header to deploy/release my artifacts to Maven Central, and I suspect their validity check won't let it pass either.

Comment: Do you have single or double asterisks at the beginning of the license block? I verified if it's single it's not formatting them

Comment: It is generated with double asterisks. I can confirm it won't be formatted when using single asterisks but the Maven plugin does not accept it.

Comment: That's interesting I see single asterisks all over the codes from Apache. 
Ex: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html

Comment: Yeah, it has already been issued: https://github.com/mycila/license-maven-plugin/issues/118

Comment: ah that was a bug :)

Comment: Maybe I'll do a pull request then. It annoys me quite a lot although this plugin is pretty handy at all. Anyway thanks for the help. Haven't thought about using single asterisks. Was looking for a proper definition but couldn't find any.