# Intellij IDEA -How to split method call into multiple lines

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA 2016.3.1. This is my java code (rest assured library):

```
when().get("/users").then().statusCode(200).body("", is(empty()));
```

This is how I want it to be:

```
when()
     .get("/users")
.then()
     .statusCode(200)
     .body("", is(empty()));
```

But, Intellij IDEA only allows me to do only this:

```
when()
         .get("/users").then().statusCode(200).body("", is(empty()));
```

How do I fix it ?

**ANSWER** - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9781/auto-formatting-restassured-test-cases-in-my-ide

Comment: Don't waste time fighting the code formatter.

Comment: @Thilo - Does that mean I cannot format my code for better readability in Intellij IDEA ?

Comment: How should it know not to indent `.then()`?

Comment: I doubt it's possible without a custom formatter.

Comment: @testerjoe2 It means you should format your code manually when you want a small piece of code to have different formatting.

Comment: @4castle additionally it means you'd have to annotate that block of code to prevent auto-formatting when you do it at the file level - at least that's what you had to do for Eclipse, not sure if IntelliJ has an equivalent thing.

Comment: @nevets1219 Yes, you can use annotations [like these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19492318/5743988).

Comment: @4castle - It does not work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments

Comment: @testerjoe2 Sorry, that's not enough information for me to be of any help.

Comment: @4castle - I put my code between off and on and I still cannot fix the formatting.

Comment: Just use the ENTER and space keys.

Comment: @LewBloch - That works. But, I have to first remove the dot for the method call I want to move around, then move it using enter and space/tab and finally re insert the dot.

Comment: I agree to *"How should it know not to indent .then() ?"*

Comment: I've used all the major IDEs for Java, and not one needed one to remove the dot to format a line.

Comment: This question is answered here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9781/auto-formatting-restassured-test-cases-in-my-ide

Comment: @MKorsch - Thanks ! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it already has an answer in another community (SQA). I have added a link to that answer in this question itself. But, please don't delete/hide this question. I am sure that people outside of SQA jobs would have this question too.