# Apache Camel and Intellij Idea code format

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-camel

Intellij Idea formats code in camel routs like this:

```
from("direct:loop")
     .log("Loop: ${header[loopCount]}")
     .choice()
     .when(simple("header[loopCount] < 10"))
     .process(exchange -> {
         Message in = exchange.getIn();
         in.setHeader("loopCount", in.getHeader("loopCount", Integer.class) + 1);
     })
     .to("direct:loop")
     .otherwise()
     .log("Exiting loop")
     .end();
```

Is there any plugins or other ways to do like this:

```
from("direct:loop")
 .log("Loop: ${header[loopCount]}")
 .choice()
     .when(simple("header[loopCount] < 10"))
         .process(exchange -> {
             Message in = exchange.getIn();
             in.setHeader("loopCount", in.getHeader("loopCount", Integer.class) + 1);
         })
         .to("direct:loop")
     .otherwise()
         .log("Exiting loop")
 .end();
```

?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html.

Comment: close voter - why is this off-topic? it's a clear question about a DSL and a programming tool. If you don't understand the question, please ask why.

Comment: @well - I never found a way to do this, so just don't format the code. It's nice to have the indenting in the DSL code... just never use the auto format feature.

Answer (score 9):

Starting from Camel IDEA plugin v 0.9.9, it is now possible to reformat your routes written with the Java DSL thanks to the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on a complete file or on a specific text range as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Reformat a route in Java]

---

Original Answer

There is a ticket about this for the Camel IDEA plugin: https://github.com/camel-idea-plugin/camel-idea-plugin/issues/309

You can use the +1 to indicate its something desired.

I personally would also like to have such feature but haven't had much spare time to work on this as I am busy with regular work, and also finishing my Camel book.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is yet a nice plugin that can format Java DSL code as desired.

At best we can only disable formatting the specific DSL parts in Java code. I would recommend to use the formatter on/off feature in IntelliJ IDEA for Camel DSL routes:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

You can find the `Formatter Control` settings in `Preferences...` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` (as of 2017.2.3).

Refer to other StackOverflow questions such as this for more details on the IntelliJ feature:
[How to disable code formatting for some part of the code using comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments)

Comment: Yes, I have found this solution before, but I thought there should be a better way to do it. Thanks for answer.