# Forbid WebStorm formatting '>>>' when using Vue

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

There is a `>>>` feature of Vue but the WebStorm's default format operation always format it to be `> > >`.

Can we disable the format of this globally?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19492318/1640606

Comment: @samayo  have seen that, but under that case we have to config wherever using the operator. A possible global config seems more elegant