# IntelliJ: add formatter:off/on comments around selected block

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

In IntelliJ IDEA (for Java code at least), it's poissble to instruct the code-formatter to ignore lines with these (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19492318/117750):

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

What I'd like to do is automate adding these around a code block. Workflow I want:

1. Select a block of code.
2. Invoke an action (with a shortcut or a menu item etc. or with the `Cmd-Shit-A`).

This command needs to

- add `// @formatter:off` on a new line **before the first selected line**, at the correct indentation.
- add `// @formatter:on` on a new line **after the last selected line**, at the correct indentation.

From what I am reading, it is not possible to do with a Macro. Is it?

If not, do I need to write a plugin to do this? I am happy to write one, can someone give me brief high-level get-started steps on:

- how to approach this action in a plugin
- and pointers to get-started with plugins

Answer (score 4):

You can get (close to) what you want using a Live Template. Go to `Editor | Live Templates` in the settings and add a new template (e.g. under the *surround* group) with the following text:

```
// @formatter:off
$SELECTION$
// @formatter:on
```

[image: live template settings example]

You can use the defined live template by selecting some text in the editor and invoking `Code | Surround with Live Template...` (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) and selecting the live template you have created.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I want. But when I select a block of code, and run this template, it inserts the comments but removes the original code :(

Comment: Strange. Is the `Edit variables` button enabled for you?

Comment: No, it's not. But $SELECTION$ is highlighted, suggesting that is correct.

Comment: Could you please share you idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: I see nothing added to the log at all when I run this step.

Comment: Do you use any custom plugins?