# VSCode: disable code formatting on small portion of code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, formatting, inline-assembly

So I am working on a bootloader in an embedded c environment. In order for the bootloader to "jump" some assembly language is required within the .c file.

Is there a way similar to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments) (or other), in VSCode that allows for temporary disabling of formatting?

Just to clarify further the code looks like this:

```
__asm void boot_jump(uint32_t address)
{
LDR SP, [R0];   Load new stack pointer address
LDR PC,     [ R0, #4 ]; Load new program counter address
}
```

and VSCode keeps formatting this code to:

```
__asm void boot_jump(uint32_t address)
{
LDR SP, [R0];
Load new stack pointer address
    LDR PC,
    [ R0, #4 ];
Load new program counter address
}
```

Which will cause compile errors and will not build. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your code to use C comment delimiters such as:

```
__asm void boot_jump(uint32_t address)
{
LDR SP, [R0];   // Load new stack pointer address
LDR PC,     [ R0, #4 ]; // Load new program counter address
}
```

Then the formatter will do nothing more that indent the code, which is benign (and prettier):

```
__asm void boot_jump(uint32_t address)
{
    LDR SP, [R0];       // Load new stack pointer address
    LDR PC, [ R0, #4 ]; // Load new program counter address
}
```

Comment: Uh man, so simple it hurts! Would still be nice to know if it's possible to selectively disable formatting though.