# Intellij Code cleanup ignore comments from being scanned and corrected

Tags: intellij-idea, code-cleanup

I am using Intellij to perform code cleanups .
I just want to skip the comments from being scanned / checked 
I want to avoid that.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what your looking for, but I hope this might help

- Activate Formatter Control in Comments: File/Settings... / Editor / Code Styles
- Replace your Comments (regex could help a lot here)
- > // @formatter:off
  >   your comments...
  >  
  >   // @formatter:on

[image]

[also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375307/how-to-disable-code-formatting-for-some-part-of-the-code-using-comments)

Answer (score 0):

Code cleanup in IDEA is a batch run of inspections, can you please give an example where you want the code not to be changed? Probably that can be done simply by excluding the particular inspection from the *Inspection profile* during cleanup.